# Google calendar API delay in sending calendar invites

Tags: javascript, nestjs, google-calendar-api, delay

I have a JS application using the google calendar api, the event is created with the event link but calendar invites usually takes time to be sent to my  calendar as the primary owner and sometimes i do not get it. Below is the code snippet, kindly help check it out.

```
addEvent = async (interview_schedule: any): Promise<any> => {
    const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3' });
    const event: any = {
      summary: interview_schedule.interview.title || 'N/A',
      description: interview_schedule.interview.description || 'N/A',
      anyoneCanAddSelf: false,
      start: {
        dateTime: new Date(
          `${interview_schedule.date} ${interview_schedule.start_time}`,
        ),
        timeZone: 'Africa/Lagos',
      },
      end: {
        dateTime: new Date(
          `${interview_schedule.date} ${interview_schedule.end_time}`,
        ),
        timeZone: 'Africa/Lagos',
      },
      attendees: interview_schedule.attendees,
      reminders: {
        useDefault: false,
        overrides: [
          { method: 'email', minutes: 60 },
          { method: 'popup', minutes: 10 },
        ],
      },
      conferenceData: {
        createRequest: {
          requestId: interview_schedule.id,
          conferenceSolutionKey: 'hangoutsMeet',
        },
      },
    };
    try {
      const res = await calendar.events.insert({
        calendarId: 'primary',
        auth: this.client,
        sendUpdates: 'all',
        conferenceDataVersion: 1,
        requestBody: event,
      });
      console.log('done creating event ', res)
      return res.data;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };
```

I have tried searching for sulutions yet no results